# Do Java class files know about white space?

Tags: java, decompiler

I wrote a Java program then compiled it and then decompiled it and got a Java file back. The decompiler gave back the exact Java file with exact indentations as my original Java file, but that is what decompilers do, this is not a problem the thing that burned the question in my mind is indentation.

As decompiled Java file have the exact same indentation as the original I conclude that class files store indentation data too.

Now the questions are as follows:

1. Is my conclusion correct?

If yes:

2. Why does a class file need to know about the indentation?
3. Indentation is meant for readability and no human reads class files, so why can't class file just not store it and save some space?
4. Are class files just an encrypted Java source file in which decompilers can decrypt to give the original back?

Comment: Have you tried messing up the indentation in your source file and see if it's reflected in the decompiled version?

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica noted for the future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compiled class files **do not** contain exact whitespace information of the source file.

There are two possible reasons that I can think of that your decompiled class files look exactly like your input:

- you happen to have written your original input with a style matching what the decompiler uses
- you didn't actually look at the decompiled source, but at the original file somehow (for example because the decompiler didn't write the output where you thought it did)

They *do* contain line numbers associated with the code that's executed to help with debugging.

But try adding a few random spaces into some of your expressions and you'll see that the decompiler can't reconstruct those.

And no, class files are not a simple "encryption" of the source files, plenty of information is lost when compiling (and some information taking from referenced classes might actually be added, such as the specific signatures of methods that are called).

You can even turn off debugging information during compilation to strip even more information (like local variable names, for example).

Comment: "you happen to have written your original input with a style matching what the decompiler uses" Java has quite a strong sense of how code should be formatted, and note that many IDE's have code formatters that adhere to this principle. Heck, maybe the source formatting and decompiled code formatting is performed by the same formatter of the IDE?

Comment: You might want to add that the way to turn off debug info is to pass `-g:none` to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

> As decompiled Java file have the exact same indentation as the
>   original I conclude that class files stores indentation data too

Why would you conclude that based on a single observation?

Why did you not at least assume the possibility of it being a coincidence? Most Java code style follows fairly standard conventions. Its distinctly possible that the decompiler and you have very similar ideas about how to lay out the same Java code.

Anyway, you could have easily tested your hypothesis. Just write a Java class with some extremely non-standard indentation - [perhaps no whitespace or linebreaks at all](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) - and see what the result is then.

You will find that your hypothesis is incorrect.

Comment: I was trying to save a well written answer, but sorry, this is just duplicate info as it stands. You're right, I'll just downvote from now on.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica I disagree but if your concern is for future readers then I don't understand why you brought up the "15 minute" gap in the first place. Either the answer is "a duplicate" or it isn't. Either it answers the question or it doesn't. Either it is the best answer or it isn't. The time at which was written is irrelevant.